Keycloak theme customization
I have a requirement to create custom theme in keycloak for my users,is there anyway to create custom theme dynamically,from java or keycloak SPI or some other approach other than customization through ftl,without any restart or downtime in keycloak?
I am going through the documentation,but couldn't find anything

You can use Keycloakify
https://willwill96.github.io/the-ui-dawg-static-site/en/keycloakify/
You can use this for reference
